# Ajax call in razor code refreshes the page

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api, razor

I'm populating a folder structure using TreeView in .cs file, rendering it in the view.cshtml. When an item is clicked, I call a js function which makes an ajax call to the web api, gets the file content and supposed to display the result in a TextArea or Div.

The result comes back from web api, and displays it in the textarea momentarily and disappears. I guess it's refreshing the page. But I'm not sure how to prevent it. I have done similar stuffs before, didn't behave so. I'm sure I'm missing something, but I can't tell what I'm missing.

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<form>
    <div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
        <div style="width: 600px; float: left;">
            <ul>
                @foreach (var node in Model.Nodes[0].ChildNodes)
                {
                    <li>@node.Text</li>
                    <ul>
                        @foreach (var f in node.ChildNodes)
                        {
                            <li><a href="" onclick="getLog('@f.Value')">@f.Text</a></li>
                        }
                    </ul>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="divLog" style="margin-left: 620px;overflow:auto;"><textarea id="txtLog" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea></div>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
    function getLog(fileref) {
        var baseURL = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '@Url.Content("~")';
        var apiUrl = baseURL + "/api/logapi?fileref=" + fileref;

        document.getElementById("txtLog").innerText = "";

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: apiUrl,
                type: "GET",
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    document.getElementById("txtLog").innerText = data;
                    //document.getElementById("txtLog").innerHTML = data;
                    //$("#txtLog").val(data);

                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: document ready inside of a function call that gets called on click does not make any sense. Cancel the click action.

Comment: 'document.ready' is one of my trial and error efforts. I removed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used button instead of anchor link, it works as expected, it doesn't refresh the screen.

```
<style>
    .btn1 {
        background-color: transparent;
        border: hidden;
    }
</style>

<li><input type="button" id="a" value="@f.Text" onclick="getLog('@f.Value')" class="button btn1"></li>
```

Comment: Oh the problem is that the anchor link has an empty href attribute then.

Comment: Somehow I didn't see that you mentioned it already in your previous response, may be because you put it after the code block. I need not have changed it to button.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe another solution for any people coming here. I had the same issue in my Razor pages project when trying to call an Ajax function from a form. The page would call the correct page handler and return the Json result, however the page would always refresh, and the success part in the ajax call would not be called. What worked FOR ME was to REMOVE the form element and replace it with a div. Now the Ajax call returns correctly for me.

```
       <div id="first" class="section"> //WHEN THIS WAS FORM THE PAGE REFRESHED
            <div class="section">
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PersonId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ProviderId)
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()                   
                <div class="container2">
                    <input type="radio" name="group1" id="radio-1" checked="checked">
                    <label for="radio-1"><span style="font-size:16px;" class="radio">I want to recieve all Emails (personal and marketing)</span></label>
                </div>
             <button onclick="setPreferences()" class="btn btn-save">Save&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
          </div>
       </div>
```

And the ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/UserPreferences?handler=SetPreferences',          
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        headers: {
            RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
        },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
           }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the Ajax call from  the `document ready` function:

```
function getLog(fileref) {
    var baseURL = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '@Url.Content("~")';
    var apiUrl = baseURL + "/api/logapi?fileref=" + fileref;

    document.getElementById("txtLog").innerText = "";

        $.ajax({
            url: apiUrl,
            type: "GET",
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                document.getElementById("txtLog").innerText = data;
                //document.getElementById("txtLog").innerHTML = data;
                //$("#txtLog").val(data);

                alert(data);
            }
        });
}
```

Secondly, replace the empty href attribute of the anchor link by `href="javascript:;"` or `href="#"`.

Comment: Didn't work either way. But I figured the issue, it's the anchor link. I switched to button, it works. I posted my answer.